# Finding a representation for Joint probability density function of dependent random variables

Tags: dependence, joint-probability

Suppose that $\underline{\mathbf{X}}=(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ is a vector of independent random variables. Then, we know that the joint probability density function $f_{\underline{\mathbf{X}}}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ is given by the following relation

\begin{equation}
f_{\underline{\mathbf{X}}}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = \prod_{j=1}^{n}f_{X_j}(x_j)
\end{equation}
Now, assume that the above random vector contains dependent random variables, in which case the joint probability density function is given by

\begin{equation}
f_{\underline{\mathbf{X}}}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = \prod_{j=1}^{n}f_{{X_j}|\underline{\mathbf{X}_{j-1}}}(x_j)
\end{equation}
where ${X_j}|\underline{\mathbf{X}_{j-1}}$ denotes the conditional distribution of $X_j$ given the random vector $\underline{\mathbf{X}_{j-1}} = (X_i, X_2, ..., X_{j-1})$. In a simple languhge, for $n=3$, we have that
\begin{equation}
f_{\underline{\mathbf{X}}}(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f_{X_3|X_1, X_2}(x_3)\times f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2) \times f_{X_1}(x_1)
\end{equation}
We define a new random variable $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$. Let's consider the following arbitrary function:
\begin{equation}
G = \prod_{j=1}^{n}f_{X_j|T_{j-1}}(x_j)
\end{equation}
where $f_{X_j|T_{j-1}}$ denotes the conditional distribution of $X_j$ given $T_{j-1}$. For example, for $n=3$, we have that

\begin{equation}
G = f_{X_3|T_2}(x_3)\times f_{X_2|T_1} \times f_{X_1}(x_1),
\end{equation}
My question is as follows:

If we consider the situation where $X_j's$ are dependent, for which we use the second relation for the joint density function, then what we can say about the relationship between $G$ and $f$. Is it possible to replace them with each other? Can one say that the identity holds between $G$ and $f$ in terms of the information we get from them?

Comment: I _think_ that you cannot swap $G$ and $f$ as $f$ contains the information on all variates and their joint dependencies, whereas $G$ (via $T$) only contains information on (increasing) sums.

Comment: But maybe this is a question more suited for another SE-page such as math or stats?